# Get dynamic set states in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am using the following:
react: ^16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
react-native: 0.57.4 => 0.57.4 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1

I have this method to generate dynamic states:

```
dynamicFreqState(ct,val)
{
    obj = {};
    obj['freq'+ct] = val;
    this.setState(obj);
}
```

In another method, I am setting states like this where `this.state.case_counter` is an incremental state in a map loop and `res.freq_id` is a property the response `res`:

```
this.dynamicFreqState(this.state.case_counter,res.freq_id),
```

If have no problem by calling `this.state.freq0` or `this.state.freq1`. The question is how do I dynamically call `this.state.freq0` or `this.state.freq1`?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this by creating another method:

```
getStateIndex(ct)
{
    obj = this.state;
    res = 0;
    Object.keys(obj).map(function (k){
        if(k == 'freq'+ct){
            res = obj[k];
        }
    });
    return res;
}
```

when I want to call the state created dynamically, I would insert this line:

```
this.getStateIndex(this.state.counter);
```

While that this.state.counter is increased incrementally.